# Why can't functions be overloaded by return type?

Tags: c++, types, return, overloading

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)
>   [Puzzle: Overload a C++ function according to the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/puzzle-overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value)

Because I have a library which exposes a bunch of functions in the form of:

```
bool GetVal();
double GetVal();
int GetVal();
long GetVal();
//So on.
```

And now I have to wrap these. I'd rather not rewrite the same set of functions again. I'd like to do something like

```
template<class T>
T GetVal(){}
```

But I can't seem to get this working. Any ideas?

Comment: Apart from the above link, there's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/puzzle-overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value and some others

Comment: you're saying you have a library which already overloads by return type? That sounds unlikely

Comment: @jalf: My guess is the functions are in different namespaces.

Comment: @Als: perhaps. Or maybe they actually have different names. We don't know, but the question, as it stands, implies that he has a library which already does what he says he can't do (and which is impossible), and then given this premise, he tries to do something entirely different which could be achieved with template specialization (mapping a generic `GetVal<T>()` to different implementations depending on the type of `T`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't overload on return types as it is not mandatory to use the return value of the functions in a function call expression.

For example, I can just say

```
GetVal();
```

What does the compiler do now?

Comment: The compiler could just emit an "Ambiguous return type" message and refuse to compile. This isn't enough justification by itself.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Beg to differ here. Refer $7.4.1 of "The C++ Programming Lanugage 3rd Edition" by Stroustrup

Comment: Alternatively: suppose we define `float GetVal()` and `double GetVal()`, and write `int x = GetVal();`. Now what? Either a `float` or a `double` may be implicitly converted to `int`.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: No. the compiler would not allow to define such overloads in the first place by giving an error.

Comment: I think one thing is that the language simply doesn't allow it, the other thing is why not. "What does the compiler do now?" - It could emit an error, which would be a good thing, because it is likely a logical error not to use (or explicitly ignore) the result. As to Karl's "Now what?" - the exact same reasoning could also be applied to overloading on parameters: `void f(double); void f(float); f(10);` "Now what?". It's not a premise of overloading that it has to be ambiguity-free. - Besides, if you look at the linked question, overloading on return type *can* be emulated in C++.

Comment: I guess a more general form of this argument would be "should the result of calling a function depend on where it is called from?" That seems to be a dangerous principle. If I call a function `F(x)`, the result should be the same no matter who I am and where I called it from and what I plan to do with the result.

Comment: @jalf But in this case int F(x) and double F(x) are two different functions. In any case, even calling int F(x) twice is never guaranteed to return the same result due to it storing data internally (via static variables) or returning different results based on other class variables or external data sources it is accessing. A guarantee that a function F(x) will always return the same result is only possible in a few specialty languages that impose a lot of other restrictions in order to make that guarantee, and C++ is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of functions is not a part of the mangled name which is generated by the compiler for uniquely identifying each function. Each of the following:

- Number of arguments
- Type of arguments
- Sequence of arguments

are the parameters which are used to generate the unique mangled name for each function. It is on the basis of these unique mangled names that compiler can understand which function to call even if the names are same(overloading).

Comment: Even if return type was used for name mangling, it would not be possible to determine the exact function to be called if the return value of the function call was discarded.

Comment: To be precise: the fact that name mangling doesn't account for the return type is a result, not a cause. If the standard had said that it was possible, name mangling qwould have included the return type.

Comment: @Chubsdad,MSalters: Agreed, point well made!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. `template <typename T> T GetVal(T) {...}` instead (using a dummy variable to perform resolution)
2. Use type conversions

Or just use the simplistic `GetValBool` etc.

Comment: There's no difference between `template<class T> T GetVal()` and `template<typename T> T GetVal()`, and the question says that the first doesn't work.  Of course, it would be nice to know why nakiya believes that, but without asking that 1. isn't too useful.

Comment: @ephemient:  Look again--he's passed a dummy parameter to make overloading work.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one function in C++ that can be overloaded by return type, the implicit conversion operator special function, named `operator T()` (with `T` varying).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't overload based on the return type.

From standard docs., Sec *13.1.2*,

> — **Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded.**

And regarding your library, each function might belong to a different namespace or else it ain't possible either.