# In overloading why the return type of the function is not considered?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Hi,

In overloading we say that the parameter list has to be different either by number or by type, but doesn't matter on the return type, Why is that so???

The function

```
//Function 1
int Add(int a, int b)
{return a+b;}

//Function 2
Double Add(Double a, Double b)
{return a+b;}

//Function 3
Double Add(int a, int b)
{return (Double)a+b;}
```

The functions 1 2 are overloaded, where as functions 1 and 3 are not ??? Reasons ???

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331837/why-cant-functions-be-overloaded-by-return-type-closed or quite a few others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=overload+return+type+c%2B%2B

Comment: do note that 1 `?` is equally fine as 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler needs to know at compile time *which* function you are trying to call. If they differ only by return type, this is usually not possible. Consider, for example:

```
var result = Add(1, 2);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(Add(1, 2));
```

the compiler would not be able to know whether you want to execute function 1 or 3. And even if you did

```
double x = Add(1, 2);
```

the compiler would not know if you (a) want to call function 3 or (b) call function 1 and do an implicit widening conversion from int to double.

Answer (score 4):

There are to many cases where that kind of overloading would not work. Here is two of them:

- You don't care about the result of the method, and call it like this:

  ```
  Add(3, 4);
  ```

Should this call method 1 or 3?

- You use `var`to assign the result

  ```
  var result = Add(3, 4);
  ```

This kind of overloading would be ambiguous at best, so therefore it's not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers deal with *why*, but an aside: in C# you can *simulate* return-type based overloading by using (abusing?) implicit conversion operators (and deferring the operation):

```
using System;
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        int i = Add(3, 5); // prints: int overload called
        double d = Add(3, 5); // prints: double overload called
    }
    static SuperMagicAdder Add(int a, int b)
    { return new SuperMagicAdder(a, b); }
}
struct SuperMagicAdder {
    private readonly int a,b;
    public SuperMagicAdder(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
    public override string  ToString() { return a + "+" + b; }
    public static implicit operator int (SuperMagicAdder value) {
        Console.WriteLine("int overload called");
        return value.a + value.b;
    }
    public static implicit operator double (SuperMagicAdder value) {
        Console.WriteLine("double overload called");
        return (double)value.a + value.b;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Combine this with partial classes, and you have pure Evil.

Answer (score 1):

Note that interestingly, Anonymous Function Literals in C# *are* overloaded on their result type and it doesn't seem to pose any problems.

In C#, a lambda can be two very different things:

- a piece of executable code (a subclass of `Delegate` actually)
- an abstract representation of an operation (basically, an abstract syntax tree)

This is distinguished *purely* by the *result type* of the lambda literal:

```
Func<int, int> l = (i) => i + i * i;
```

is a piece of executable code. I can say

```
Console.WriteLine(l(3));
```

and I will get `12`.

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> e = (i) => i + i * i;
```

is an *abstract representation* of that operation. I can say

```
Console.WriteLine(e);
```

and I will get

```
i => (i + (i * i))
```

Note that this is *not just* the original text. It really *is* an rendering of the abstract representation. The extra parentheses around the expression and inside it are there, because `ToString()` did an actual tree traversal of the AST and rendered it. The AST looks roughly like this:[image: Expression Tree]

And this

```
var v = (i) => i + i * i;
```

is simply illegal, *because* lambdas are overloaded on their result type, but the `var` keyword says "use the result type to figure out the type of `v`".

Comment: CAn you give (or link to) an example of what you mean? I can't work out in my head how you would do something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Allowing return types to be part of the signature would create major ambiguities in overload resolution.

For example, consider:

```
Add(2,3);
```

We are "throwing away" the value returned by the method, but *which* overload should be invoked?

It doesn't work well with implicit-typing, or with assigning the value to a variable that is compatible with either return-type. E.g.:

```
var sum = Add(2,3);
object sum = Add(2,3);
```

Comment: OTOH, if it was allowed, then the returned value of such a function and its type would be significant to the caller, so the caller would not be tempted to use any of those ambiguous calls. You and everybody else are focusing on ambiguous uses, disregarding potential valid use cases. Why not make it an error only if the call is indeed ambiguous?

Comment: @visitor: It would be painful for the programmer to resolve the ambiguities in all cases, i.e. telling the compiler which method to bind to. Imagine if there was a `string Foo(int bar)` and `object Foo(int bar)`. Now, imagine we wanted to use a method-group conversion from the former method to a `Func<int, object>` (contravariant). This suddenly becomes a minor headache.