# Calling a function or constructor of the class with same name. Which compiler gets it right?

Tags: c++

According to Godbolt, this code compiles with MSVC but not with GCC and Clang [[conformance view](https://godbolt.org/z/5x5nhWc5b)]. Which one is right and why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void Example (){
    std::cout << "function";
}

class Example{ 
    public: Example() { 
        std::cout << "constructor";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example();
    class Example();
}
```

I understand that [the function will be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341979/what-happens-when-a-class-and-a-function-have-the-same-name), which is why I wrote `class` in the second line.

Comment: try conformance view https://godbolt.org/z/5x5nhWc5b

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: didn't even know godbolt had such a thing. Cool!

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is but all three compilers accept (IMHO correctly) `using Ex = class Example; Ex();`

Comment: @Peter This is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: Meta: How can a question be closed as duplicate without me seeing who closed it? Usually I'd see 3 names or a gold badge.

Comment: @ThomasWeller This was a somewhat recent change to make close votes less personal and prevent vendettas. Other users with close privileges can still see the close voters.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: with 53k I thought I had all privileges possible.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yeah I'm confused too. Maybe it's because it was closed by a single user via the [c++] gold badge privilege, and you not having the gold badge means you can't see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe MSVC is not standard-conforming in this case. [Elaborated type specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) are not allowed in [functional-style cast expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

Expressions in the form `T()` are called functional-style cast expressions. [[expr.type.conv]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.type.conv) gives its precise syntax:

> A *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed by a parenthesized optional expression-list or by a braced-init-list

Sadly neither [*simple-type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.simple#nt:simple-type-specifier) nor [*typename-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier) allow elaborated type specifiers so `class T()` is illegal.

cppreference has a more comprehensible explanation: `T` must be a single word type name (with optional qualification and template arguments). `int()`, `std::string()`, `std::vector<int>()` are OK, while `unsigned int()`, `class std::vector<int>()` are not OK.