# Can a variable and a method have the same name in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, boolean, naming, names

```
class Controller {

 bool isBackendActive();
 void anotherMethodDoingSomething();

}
```

Can I declare a boolean variable with the same name as a method so that I can use it like this:

```
void Controller::anotherMethodDoingSomething() {
    bool isBackendActive = isBackendActive();
    if (aBoolean && isBackendActive) {
     ...
     LOG("bla" + isBackendActive)
    }
    else if (!isBackendActive) {
     ...
    }
    else 
     ...
    }
```

Thank you a lot for your input in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that, even if it were possible? Do you want to confuse anyone who reads the code?

Comment: No you can't have variables and functions with the same name in the same scope. The only exception is class and structure tag names (like your name `Controller`), which lives in a separate name-space.

Comment: If they have different scopes, you might (but one hides the other).

Comment: You also have 2 variables with the same name (a local one and a class member)

Comment: @UnholySheep To only call isBackendActive once. I need the result more than once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't a class have same name for a function and a data member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763802/why-cant-a-class-have-same-name-for-a-function-and-a-data-member)

Comment: @Odysseus Thanks a lot: I have fixed my question and removed my mistake (no 2 variables with the same name anymore).

Comment: Even it is possible, that is the point where naming conventions should take place. If there is no indication if an identifier is a type/function/object  nobody can read the code anymore. Always tracking back to the definitions is a nighmare!

Comment: @Klaus Yes your point is well known to me. I would have prefered this:

class Backend { 
 public:
  bool isActive();
}

class Controller {

 void anotherMethodDoingSomething {
    Backend backend;
    bool isBackendActive = backend.isActive();
    ...
}

But I mustnot change the old code anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without discussing merits (or lack thereof), yes, you can disambiguate a member from a local variable rather easily.

```
bool const isBackendActive = this->isBackendActive();
```

or

```
bool const isBackendActive = Controller::isBackendActive();
```

Will work (and might as well be const correct).

Comment: Great. Thank you a lot. I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the compiler error messages:

```
 error: 'isBackendActive' cannot be used as a function
   43 |         bool isBackendActive = isBackendActive( );
      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

It's not possible.

You can rename your function using `snake_case` to make them different:

```
bool is_backend_active( );
```

If you don't want to do that then:

```
bool isBackendActive = this->isBackendActive( );
```

Use of `this` will give the compiler enough info about what you want. It tells the compiler that you want to have access to a member (a variable or a function) of the class `Controller` and not a local variable like `bool isBackendActive;`

Comment: uh useful trick thanks.

Comment: For a local variable `isBackendActive` and a member function `isBackendActive()`, the `this->` could resolve it: `bool isBackendActive = this->isBackendActive();`. As @Jarod42 already pointed out: In your case the local variable and the member function are defined in separate scopes, and members might become eclipsed by local definitions but can be addressed explicitly with `this` (or a scope operator).

Comment: @Scheff's Cat Yes right. Good point.

Comment: Thanks for expanding the answer. It is clear to me now.

Comment: @artacademy You're welcome. Check the answer for more explanation about that.