# Overload function of operator with enum type data

Tags: c++, enums

Use the enum below to implement the next 3 operators

```
enum day {
Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
};
day *operator++(day &d);
day &operator--(day &d);
day const &operator--(day &d);
```

This is my code:

```
day *operator++ (day &d) 
{
    d = (day)(d + 1);
    return &d;
}
day &operator--(day &d)
{
    d = (day)(d - 1);
    return d;
}
day const &operator--(day &d) 
{
    d = (day)(d - 1);
    return d;
}
```

But I get my a overload function with the 3rd func. How can i fix it?

Comment: [You cannot overload a function by its return type alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331837/why-cant-functions-be-overloaded-by-return-type)

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the last `operator`, anyway?

Comment: Returning a pointer from `operator++` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Nope, it is a pointer alright.

Comment: I'm not sure Saturday+1 and Sunday-1 will work as intended unless you use a modulo here...

Answer (score 1):

As said by @NathanOliver, C++ does not allow programmer to have overloads that differ only by the return type. So your third and last overload cannot coexists with second one.

Anyway, you should not write the first overload either. Common programmers use `++` operator and syntactic sugar for `x = x+1` (more or less because of the difference between prefix and postfix versions).

But it is really weird that the `operator++` or the addition returns a **pointer**. It is at least confusing, even if syntactically acceptable by the compiler.