# Optimizing vector assignment c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a function which returns a vector. Let's name it `v`. I use `v.begin()` and `v.end()` in a function. How could I make using `.begin()` and `.end()` without creation a new vector `v2` to store the previous vector `v` so I can get access to methods?

Here's what I mean:

```
std::vector<int> merge(...) {
    ...
    return v;
}
void mergeSort(...) {
    ...
    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2 = merge(...);
    I_need_this = v2.begin();
    And_I_really_need_this_too = v2.end();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to optimize assignment is to not assign at all, but use initialization

```
std::vector<int> v2 = merge(...);
```

It is almost certain that the compiler will create `v` directly into `v2`, without any copying.

Comment: By using the `move` constructor

Comment: I tried it before post was created. It didn't work well.

Comment: Try std::vector<int> v2 = std::move(merge(...));

Comment: @Vincent `merge(....)` is already an rvalue, so that would actually be a pessimization

Comment: @ValeryBaturin this is the right answer, if you are still having problems then there is another error you didn't show the code for. It would be much better if you posted an actual program that shows the problem, instead of a bunch of dots. [See here for guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GioraGuttsait No, most likely by eliding the copy.

Comment: Thank you, I've got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern when you need to return collections, in order to prevent them from being copied, is to pass the collection by non-const reference and to make the changes to the original. This means that the caller is responsible for instantiating the collection, not the callee, and as such no copy ever occurs. Here's an example:

```
void merge(std::vector<int> & result, ...) {

    // Do changes to result
    ...
}
void mergeSort(...) {
    ...
    std::vector<int> v;
    merge(v, ...);

    // This is OK now
    I_need_this = v.begin();
    And_I_really_need_this_too = v.end();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do not like this cause you always need to create vector before using function. But it's a solution anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Fine by me, but I hope you understand that this is the _de facto_ standard when it comes to returning collections. The accepted answer will still create a copy in some situations, and usually it's a good idea to design your code to cover a wide variety of scenarios. Remember, for instance, that in C you cannot even return arrays. And besides, what's the problem with creating it before if you are creating it anyway? Happy coding!

Comment: @AndréFratelli:  Two biggest problems with creating it before setting its value a) you can't declare it `const` ; b) it's very poor style. It's also a potential problem if the caller reuses a variable and forgets to clear it.

Comment: @MartinBonner I could agree that you can't declare it const, however you can make a const copy. Considering being very poor style, that's where you get it very wrong. Like I said, this is the **de facto** standard in programming when it comes to returning collections, and you'll find it quite a lot in literature. The fact that you don't like it is irrelevant, as it is indeed how this problem is usually solved, even when move constructors are available. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898021/c-newbie-question-designing-a-function-to-return-a-vector-of-either-string-or) discussion

Comment: It is not the de facto standard; it is one of the choices - usually a poor one.  That discussion is about one of the cases where it does have *some* advantages (overload by return type) - but the right solution there would be have different function names (although that can be problematic in templated code).

Comment: So the "right solution" would be problematic? You are ignoring major advantages of this pattern, such as accumulating over several calls (if changes are made to it). I'll repeat: this **is** the _de facto_ standard to solve this problem, which you'll find in plenty literature and as I learned in college. I admit that this changed with move semantics, but if that's the case update your tags to refer to C++11, not C++. And yes, this distinction is important: generally speaking, in C++ you don't return a vector by value and that's a terrible idea, regardless of whether you like the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your vector temporary to a reference:

```
extern std::vector<int> f();

auto&& x = f();
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());  // example
```

Comment: ‘function’ has both ‘extern’ and initializer
         extern std::vector<int> function(...);

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

1. Don't worry about it.  Performance is usually not that important.
2. Turn on optimization (you would be amazed how many "optimization" questions on SO are solved by that step).
3. Upgrade to a C++11 compiler.  The compiler should use the move assignment operator for vector, which is very efficient (any decent library will transfers the internally allocated array from the temporary to the target with no memory allocation and no copying of elements).
4. If you can't use a C++11 compiler, or you've measured, and this is still a performance bottleneck, switch to initialization as suggested by Bo Person in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35107954/771073)
5. If you've measured, and this is *still* a performance bottleneck, and you can't get your compiler to implement the RVO, then you have no choice but to pass the vector in by value as suggest by André Fratelli in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35107912/771073)

If we step back from discussing optimization, and discuss writing good, clear, code, then I would recommend in order of preference:

- Initialization from function result
- Assignment from function result
- Pass in vector to be filled.

Comment: I could use c++11 but had no option to make program slow. I had a contest with time limits and so. Thank you for your answer. RVO is cool, I heard about it.