# How to get property type passed to T in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, types

Ok,

Here is what I'm doing, I have a class called Settings
Settings has a list of properties:

I'm trying to make it as dynamic as possible.
So I can just copy and paste each property and just change its name
and it will grab the new setting by the name

Example..

```
public string Url
{ get { return Get<string>(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()); } }
public int Port
{ get { return Get<int>(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()); } }

private T Get<T>(MethodBase method)
{
  // Code that pulls setting from the property name
}
```

Question is, how can I pass the properties type to Get, that way I don't have to specify the data type twice..

I know this is wrong but sort of like

```
Get<MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetType()>(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question - but I'd strongly reconsider this approach. Not only is the code almost gratuitously obfuscated (compare with `Get<int>("Port")` for example) but the performance will be poor due to reflection, and renaming properties during future refactoring could break your code as people may not realise the property name is used as effectively a dictionary key (see previous comments about obfuscation).

Comment: main reason I'm doing this is to centralize where I get my settings, rather than having the code all over the project, and if I decide to change where I'm reading settings from, it is not a nightmare to do, I'm using reflection just the get the property name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to infer a return type; you cannot do this using generics.

If `Get` doesn't use `typeof(T)`, you can change it to return `dynamic` instead of using generics. 
The caller can then implicitly cast the result in its `return` statement.

There may be a performance penalty, though.

Comment: In [C++ you can do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/puzzle-overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value), but it seems that in C# you can't :(

Comment: This worked great, if there will be a performance penalty, doubt it'll be very noticeable, will run load tests once I'm done to see how much it'll be

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like

```
Get<MethodThatReturnsAType()>
```

because the generic type is set at compile time. I'm sort of wondering what the advantage you're getting here is. You could have the Get simply return object and manage the cast in the property.

What behaviour do you expect if the setting is missing for example, or defined but the wrong type?

Comment: reason I need this is so I can create settings just by copying pasting a previous setting and just change its name and datatype, i actually have my settings in db, so it grabs setting from db by property name