# Converting all functions into classes

Tags: c++, refactoring, oop

I was reading the book *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Fowler, where it says to replace function calls with same names classes and call constructors of that class in place of original function call.

My question is is it a good idea to convert all the functions(more or less, except very trivial ones) into objects so that the code becomes more modular?

Thanks,

Comment: Please give a bit more context for people (like me) who haven’t read this book. As is, the statement sounds completely moronic. But knowing the reputation of Martin Fowler and Kent Beck, I suspect that there’s more to it.

Comment: John Carmack once twitted "Sometimes, the elegant implementation is just a function. Not a method. Not a class. Not a framework. Just a function." Don't do anything fancy in your code unless you're sure it will make it better.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what the author wanted to say there. It was something like below. Replace Method with Method Object 
You have a long method that uses local variables in such a way that you cannot apply Extract Method. 
Turn the method into its own object so that all the local variables become fields on that object. You can then decompose the method into other methods on the same object.

Comment: Right, **if** you have a large function that handles an internal state, it might be a class in disguise. In that case, you might turn it into a class with several smaller functions. On the other hand, a function that only computes a value from its parameters, is *not* improved by putting it into a class.

Comment: The book in question doesn't say, unilaterally, to do anything. It lists things which can be done, and reasons to do them. Refactoring is an art form; otherwise, the computer would do it all automatically for you. Many refactorings are reversible: sometimes you should convert A to B, and other times convert B to A.

Comment: @Bo Persson - That's exactly the right answer - you should post it.

Comment: @razlebe - I did that. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to what @Bo Persson said, this is also useful if you want to [overload a function on the return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/puzzle-overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value). :)

Comment: @Bo Persson Great - have a +1. :)

Answer (score 6):

Expanding a bit on my earlier comment:

In C++ there is absolutely no reason to turn **all** functions into classes, some kind of processing objects. Functions work well when you just have to compute and return a value.

However, **if** you have a large function that creates an internal state and uses that in several places during its processing, or (gasp!) stores some state in global variables, that function might be a class in disguise. In that case it can be a good idea to store the state in a class object with several smaller member functions doing their work on that common state.

On the other hand, a function that *only* computes a value from its parameters is *not* improved by putting it into a class.

Comment: "Method Object" is a very useful refactoring pattern, which I applied many times to long methods. It is also a good strategy for separating operations and algorithms from the data. I would not necessarily agree with "a function that only computes a value from its parameters is not improved". If the function/method is long and has lots of auto-variables (i.e. internal temporary state) applying Method Object will greatly improve the structure and maintainability of the code - even if the resulting class is not a "class in disguise" ("class" understood as a type of objects), but rather a module.

Answer (score 2):

No, why would it? If you have functionality that is logically a function (stateless computation), and there's no compelling reason to implement it as a class, then just implement it as a function.

The advice to "replace function calls with same names classes and call constructors of that class in place of original function call" is plain wrong: how can you replace

```
int y = f(x);
```

by a `class f` and a call to its constructor? A constructor doesn't have a return value! The only way to get this to work is to overload `operator()` on the `class f` so you can use one of

```
int y = f(x)();
int y = f()(x);
```

both of which are pointless. (Also, you'd have to remember which one of these you need for every function object you define.)

There must be something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, converting functions into classes is absolutely pointless. Why would you want to do that?

When you convert your functions to objects, you're not gaining anything. A method call is in fact the same plain function call, only with a hidden argument, `this`. In your case, that argument would be redundant because your object is not bearing any state.

The only reason I can think of for converting functions to objects is passing functions as objects to other functions, but for that purpose we have function pointers or boost::function or c++ 0x lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively no!
It is no point to convert *any* function to class.

Class is about to manage some state of object and hide information, functions are to global and mostly stateless. A lot of lose classes make software inefficient and unmaintainable.