# Header File Content Puzzle [Interview Question]

Tags: c++, puzzle

What should be the content of the header file `Fill.hpp` such that the following code works i.e both `assert`s work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include "Fill.hpp"

int main() 
{
  std::string s = multiply(7,6);
  int i = multiply(7,6);
  assert(s == "42");
  assert(i == 42);
}
```

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Puzzle: Overload a C++ function according to the return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/puzzle-overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define **[conversion functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr385.htm)** for converting a type `multiply` into `int` and `std::string` as shown in **Method 1** or use **Method 2** (similar to 1)

**Method 1**

```
struct multiply
{  
    int t1,t2;
    operator std::string()
    {
        std::stringstream k;
        k<<(t1*t2);
        return k.str();
    }
    operator int()
    {   
        return t1*t2;
    }
    multiply(int x, int y):t1(x),t2(y){}
};
```

**Method 2**

```
class PS
{
  int _value;
  public:
  PS(int value) : _value(value) {}    
  operator std::string() 
  {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << _value;
    return oss.str();
  }    
  operator int() 
  {
    return _value;
  }
};

PS multiply(int a, int b) 
{
  return PS(a * b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Number
{
public:
    Number(int i) { value = i; } // So that integer can be converted to class instances.

public:
    operator std::string()
    {
        return .... // Code to convert to string for first assignment to work.
    }

    operator int()
    {
        return value; // For second assignment to work.
    }

public:
    int value;

}

Number multiply(Number a, Number b)
{
    .... // code to multiply both numbers and return the result.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer I can think of:

```
// Fill.hpp
struct multiply {
  multiply(int, int) {}
  operator std::string() { return "42"; }
  operator int() { return 42; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the simple:

```
#define NDEBUG
```