# C++ multiple inheritance function name collision

Tags: c++, oop, templates

*Context: I was discussing C# vs. Java at work when the following question came up, and I wondered how (or if) it could be elegantly resolved in C++.*

Let's say you have two classes `A` and `B` (whose details are not important) and then two templated class `G` and `H` described as something like:

```
template <typename T>            | template <typename T> 
class G                          | class H
{                                | {
   public :                      |    public :
      T * foo() ;                |       virtual T * foo() = 0 ;
      // etc.                    |       // etc.
} ;                              | } ;
```

Then we have the class `C` and `D` described like:

```
class A { /* ... */ } ;
class B { /* ... */ } ;

class C : public G<A>, public G<B>
{
} ;

class D : public H<A>, public H<B>
{
   // ???
} ;
```

I want to be able to call for `C` the method `foo` from `G<A>` and foo from `G<B>`. And I want to be able to override for `D` the method `foo` from `H<A>` and `H<B>`.

In the end, I want to be able to use C and D like in the following examples:

```
C c ;
A * a = c.??? ; (I want to call G<A>::foo())
B * b = c.??? ; (I want to call G<B>::foo())

D d ;
A * a = c.??? ; (I want to call H<A>::foo())
B * b = c.??? ; (I want to call H<B>::foo())
```

There always are ways to do it (and I have some ideas), but I'm interested a list of elegant and safe ways to do it, including pros/cons.

So, **how would you do it?**

Comment: *I want to be able to call foo from G and foo from G.*, What do you mean?

Comment: You want to use the keyword "using"

Comment: Have you tried something like `G<A>::foo();` and `G<B>::foo();`?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg : This is one of the ways I throught off, but I would have liked a full answer. I'll amend my question.

Comment: @MasoudM. It's also useful for specifying a function on an inherited class.

Comment: Clear your question. *What are the different ways (I see at least two ways, but I'm interested in the pros/cons) to call them without needing to add code in C?* and *2. Let's say G is an interface, and that foo is pure virtual and needs to be implemented by C*

Comment: @Alecs : Thanks for the comment., I rephrased the question to clarify it.

Comment: Two-column code … that’s innovative. :-D

Answer (score 5):

The two ways I can think of:

```
C x;

x.G<A>::foo(); // 1
static_cast<G<A>&>(x).foo(); // 2
```

That is: either explicitly qualifying the function’s name, or upcast in the type hierarchy.

Comment: +1 - This is one answer for complication 1, and which is similar in appearance to C#'s <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx">Explicit Interface Implementation</a>. The thing is, for complication 2 (G::foo is pure virtual, and so, needs to be overridden in C), I find no elegant way to do it...

Comment: Didn't you forget the reference in the static cast? Something like `static_cast< G<A> & >(x).foo()` ?... :-)

Comment: Ah, I knew it. I had it first and the removed it … for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

How about, overloading and using different arguments :

```
template <typename T>
class G
{
public:
    T * foo(T &a) {/* ... */};
    // etc.
};

class A
{
public:
    /* ... */
};

class B
{
    public:
    /* ... */
};

class C : public G<A>, public G<B>
{
public:
    using G<A>::foo;
    using G<B>::foo;

};

int main()
{
    C c;

    A a;
    B b;

    c.foo(a);
    c.foo(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 - This is similar to one of my answers for "choosing" a function according to its return type (by putting the type through a dummy typed NULL pointer as an additional parameter) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/puzzle-overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value/228923#228923