# C++ same function parameters with different return type

Tags: c++, function, types, overloading

I need to find some way to mock an overload of a function return type in C++.

I know that there isn't a way to do that directly, but I'm hoping there's some out-of-the-box way around it.
We're creating an API for users to work under, and they'll be passing in a data string that retrieves a value based on the string information. Those values are different types. In essence, we would like to let them do:

```
int = RetrieveValue(dataString1);
double = RetrieveValue(dataString2);
// Obviously, since they don't know the type, they wouldn't use int =.... It would be:
AnotherFunction(RetrieveValue(dataString1)); // param of type int
AnotherFunction(RetrieveValue(dataString2)); // param of type double
```

But that doesn't work in C++ (obviously).
Right now, we're having it set up so that they call:

```
int = RetrieveValueInt(dataString1);
double = RetrieveValueDouble(dataString2);
```

However, we don't want them to need to know what the type of their data string is.

Unfortunately, we're not allowed to use external libraries, so no using Boost.

Are there any ways we can get around this?

Just to clarify, I understand that C++ can't natively do it. But there must be some way to get around it. For example, I thought about doing RetrieveValue(dataString1, GetType(dataString1)). That doesn't really fix anything, because GetType also can only have one return type. But I need something like that.

I understand that this question has been asked before, but in a different sense. I can't use any of the obvious answers. I need something completely out-of-the-box for it to be useful to me, which was not the case with any of the answers in the other question asked.

Comment: How will they know what type to assign the result of the function to?

Comment: You are trying to follow a bad path. Different types are diffent types, and different functions are different functions. This kind of syntactic overloading will not add any value. Instead, it will add unnecessary complexity to your code. Don't do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Puzzle: Overload a C++ function according to the return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/puzzle-overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value)

Comment: Will you show an actual way you want this function to be called? And int x = RetrieveValue(...) Isn't it because they have to specify int for x which breaks one of your conditions. I think this question is ill-conceived.

Comment: Yes, I used int = RetrieveValue(...) just as a simple example. They will actually be calling the function inside of another function. So it might be:
AnotherFunction(RetrieveValue(...),param);

Comment: This question isn't answerable in it's current form, as per Seth's comments. EDIT: Perhaps edit your question to include an example of what the real code will look like, following on from your comment above mine?

Comment: It will add some complication, but have you thought about the visitor pattern?

Comment: The method that was the accepted answer to the link that @bo-persson commented would be the way to do it.  However it would be better to use a different method if possible. i.e. return a type that has overloaded user defined conversion operators.

Comment: @Pete that doesn't work at all for this, because he's passing the return value into an overloaded function. This functionality can't be done at compile time.

Comment: @SethCarnegie didn't see that part.  And also the API part - I certainly wouldn't recommend such a technique for an API.  Can be useful in a property system though.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I still cant see that part in fact.

Comment: I believe you're using the wrong language.  Do you really need to use C++ for this?

Comment: @Pete see his comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840173/c-same-function-parameters-with-different-return-type#comment20796445_14840173

Comment: @SethCarnegie i see now.

Comment: is `dataString1` a compile-time constant? or a run-time variable?

Comment: @Walter: it's a compile-time constant. A string that has a reference deeper in the system which determines the type.

Answer (score 32):

You've to start with this:

```
template<typename T>
T RetrieveValue(std::string key)
{
     //get value and convert into T and return it
}
```

To support this function, you've to work a bit more, in order to convert the value into the type `T`. One easy way to convert value could be this:

```
template<typename T>
T RetrieveValue(std::string key)
{
     //get value
      std::string value = get_value(key, etc);

      std::stringstream ss(value);
      T convertedValue;
      if ( ss >> convertedValue ) return convertedValue;
      else throw std::runtime_error("conversion failed");
}
```

Note that you still have to call this function as:

```
int x = RetrieveValue<int>(key);
```

You could avoid mentioning `int` twice, if you could do this instead:

```
Value RetrieveValue(std::string key)
{
     //get value
      std::string value = get_value(key, etc);
      return { value };
}
```

where `Value` is implemented as:

```
struct Value
{
    std::string _value;

    template<typename T>
    operator T() const   //implicitly convert into T
    {
       std::stringstream ss(_value);
       T convertedValue;
       if ( ss >> convertedValue ) return convertedValue;
       else throw std::runtime_error("conversion failed");
    }
}
```

Then you could write this:

```
int    x = RetrieveValue(key1);
double y = RetrieveValue(key2);
```

which is which you want, right?

Comment: And as a hint for the OP, do a search for "template specialization".

Comment: But, they'll still have to specify the type in this case.  It can't be deduced.  So, instead of `RetrieveValueInt`, they'll have to write `RetrieveValue<int>`, and I don't see much of a diffence there, except for the latter's ability to be used generically.

Comment: @Benjamin They're specifying the type anyway, with `int x = `, surely?

Comment: @JonBentley: Apparently, that's not how the OP wants it to be used.  See his latest comment.  He surely has chosen the wrong language.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes, just seen that. I've suggested he edit his question.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: See my edit. :-) I think I deserve an upvote :P (or downvote? :| )

Comment: Still doesn't work, ambiguity with overloaded functions. The OP's setup had made this impossible, he needs to use some runtime facilities. And turns out he used a bogus example.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Overloaded functions? I dont see any overloaded function in my answer, do you?

Comment: No that's what he's doing with this function, calling another function. See his comments on his answer.

Comment: i want to do  `if ( ss >> std::boolalpha >> convertedValue ) return convertedValue;` when T is std::boolalpha and rest of the times, i want to do plain `if ( ss >> convertedValue ) return convertedValue;`

Comment: how would `auto` handle the return values of `RetrieveValue()`?

Answer (score 3):

The only sane way to do this is to move the return value to the parameters.

```
 void retrieve_value(std::string s, double& p);
 void retrieve_value(std::string s, int& p);
 <...>

 double x;
 retrieve_value(data_string1, x);

 int y;
 retrieve_value(data_string2, y);
```

Comment: Your order of declared parameters doesn't match the order of actual parameters.

Comment: The downside for this approach is that if using objects they must already be constructed, which might require implementing dummy constructors

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is an overload or a specialization, you'll need the information to be in the function signature. You could pass the variable in as an unused 2nd argument:

```
int RetrieveValue(const std::string& s, const int&) {
  return atoi(s.c_str());
}
double RetrieveValue(const std::string& s, const double&) {
  return atof(s.c_str());
}

int i = RetrieveValue(dataString1, i);
double d = RetrieveValue(dataString2, d);
```

Comment: I found myself using this exact same pattern to 'overload' the return type in my GUI widget creation functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your value can never be something like zero or negative, just return a struct holding int and double and zero out the one you don't need...

It's a cheap and dirty, but easy way...

```
struct MyStruct{
int myInt;
double myDouble;
};

MyStruct MyFunction(){
}
```

Comment: Or add a boolean or some third value that indicates which value should be read (int or double).  Again, this isn't optimal or elegant, but super straight-forward...A class would work as well, but no real point if you just have int and double.

Comment: We've thought about this, however, we can't have the users have to deal with a struct.

Comment: You have 2 options:  Use a class or struct, or pass params via reference, which means no return value (or at least not the int and double).  There is a horrible way you could do it:  You could return a string that held the value and type so you would have "int 1234" or "double 123.456" but then users have to decipher... Sorry, but you haven't many options.

Answer (score 1):

If the datastrings are compile-time constants (as said in answering my comment), you could use some template magic to do the job. An even simpler option is to not use strings at all but some data types which allow you then to overload on argument.

```
struct retrieve_int {} as_int;
struct retrieve_double {} as_double;

int RetrieveValue(retrieve_int) { return 3; }
double RetrieveValue(retrieve_double) { return 7.0; }

auto x = RetrieveValue(as_int);    // x is int
auto y = RetrieveValue(as_double); // y is double
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to overload the function return type see this answer 
[Overloading by return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: I'd say "Fortunately, ...".

Comment: +1 To that, yes "Fortunately" for common sense, but unfortunate if for some reason you really wan't that feature.

Comment: It's actually an amazingly useful feature in Ada, but it only works there because of Ada's lack of implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=itoa(retrieveValue(dataString));
double a=ftoa(retrieveValue(dataString));
```

both return a string.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the template solution, you can have the function return a reference or a pointer to a class, then create subclasses of that class to contain the different data types that you'd like to return. `RetrieveValue` would then return a reference to the appropriate subclass.

That would then let the user pass the returned object to other functions without knowing which subclass it belonged to.

The problem in this case would then become one of memory management -- choosing which function allocates the returned object and which function deletes it, and when, in such a way that we avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple just declare the function returning void* type and in the definition return a reference to the variable of different types. For instance in the header (.h) declare

```
void* RetrieveValue(string dataString1);
```

And in the definition (.cpp) just write

```
void* RetrieveValue(string dataString1)
{
    if(dataString1.size()<9)
    {
        static double value1=(double)dataString1.size();
        return &value1;
    }
    else
    {
        static string value2=dataString1+"some string";
        return &value2;
    }
}
```

Then in the code calling RetrieveValue just cast to the right value

```
string str;
string str_value;
double dbl_value;
if(is_string)
{
    str_value=*static_cast<*string>(RetrieveValue(str));
}
else
{
    dbl_value=*static_cast<*double>(RetrieveValue(str));
}
```

Comment: I forget to mention that the variables returned must be static in order to the values can reached from outside the function translation unit in case you making a lib.

Answer (score -2):

Since you used an example that wasn't really what you wanted, you threw everyone off a bit.

The setup you really have (calling a function with the return value of this function whose return type is unknowable) will not work because function calls are resolved at compile time.

You are then restricted to a runtime solution. I recommend the visitor pattern, and you'll have to change your design substantially to allow for this change. There isn't really another way to do it that I can see.

Comment: How wasn't my example what I wanted?

Comment: @JoshJohnson you said that the example in your question isn't how it will really be used didn't you?

Comment: It will be used as shown. It may be more directly used inside of another function call, however that would not have shown the distinction needed as clearly. The example I gave is still a valid use for the function.
You said that it 'wasn't really what I wanted'. This is not true. I do want that...

Comment: @JoshJohnson But it's not all you want. The example `int x = f(str)` and `f(g(str))` are not even close to being the same when it comes to solving how to do the return type. As I said, there's no solution to your problem as stated except what I wrote in this answer. Downvoting won't change that fact.

Comment: If I would have only given the second example, how would one have known explicitly about the different return types?
And how would that change the solution? In both cases, various return values are needed. How exactly is anything changed?

Comment: @JoshJohnson because with the example you gave, the return type must be known by the programmer because he assigns it to a variable. That's why you got 10 answers saying things like "use templates to pass the return type as an argument" or "pass another variable by reference into the function". In the case `f(g(str))`, the programmer doesn't need to know the return type because `f` can be overloaded for different types, and it renders all the proposed solutions infeasible. Know what I mean? I'm just trying to help you ask a precise question that accurately reflects your needs.