# C++ Template to return different types with same parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Basically, if I have this:

```
template <class T> 
inline T Foo(int x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            return true;
            break;
        case 1:
            return false;
            break;
        case 2:
            return 100;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I then have to use it as such:

```
int x = Foo<int>(2);
bool b = Foo<bool>(0);
```

I would much prefer to be able to do it like this, if possible:

```
int x = Foo(2);
bool b = Foo(0);
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840173/c-same-function-parameters-with-different-return-type) but struggled to apply it to my scenario. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be great.

Comment: As written, just return an `int`. The implicit conversion to `bool` will do the right thing. Also, you'd probably want something in your `default` case rather than falling through the end of the function and invoking undefined behavior - throw an exception, perhaps.

Comment: Are the values you're passing to `Foo` known at compile time? You can do `int x = Foo<2> ();` for example.

Comment: @T.C. That works in the case of just using int/bool, but what if I wanted there to be more return types?

Comment: As written, that would seem like pretty poor design then. But maybe that's because you've simplified the problem too much in your example. If you know the type you'll be getting in the return at compile time, why make a method whose switch statement's sole purpose seems to be to select the correct 'inner method' that returns that type? Why not just have different methods?

Comment: What's supposed to happen when you call `int x = Foo(3);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to use a return type which is convertible to our desired return types.
In this case, we can use string which can be converted to int, bool, double etc.. using stringstream.

```
inline polyType Foo(int x)
{
    polyType result;
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            result.value = "0";
            break;
        case 1:
            result.value = "1";
            break;
        case 2:
            result.value = "100";
            break;
        case 3:
            result.value = "awesome";
            break;
        case 4:
            result.value = "10.22";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

where polyType is to declared as the following with a type cast for any typename T as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840173/c-same-function-parameters-with-different-return-type)

```
struct polyType {
    string value;

    template <typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
       stringstream ss(value);
       T convertedValue;
       if ( ss >> convertedValue ) return convertedValue;
       else throw runtime_error("conversion failed");
    }
 };
```

Now you can use it as

```
int a = Foo(2);
bool b = Foo(0);
float c = Foo(4);
```

In your case if you want to use only int and bool. since int is convertible to bool you can just return int. Instead of returning "true" and "false" use 1 and 0.

```
int Foo(int x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            return 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            return 100;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the compiler can't implicitly determine template parameters based on return type alone. It can usually determine them implicitly if you pass them in as parameters (function templates).

So, one thing that might work better is passing the template parameters in by reference:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(int x, T& arg1)
{
    if (x == 0)
        arg1 = true;
    else if (x == 1)
        arg1 = "test";  
}

bool a = false;
std::string b;

Foo(0, a);
Foo(1, b);
```

Comment: Also, if you want multiple arguments, you could potentially use variadic templates (c++11 feature).