# Elegant way to return different value types from function in c++ / c++11

Tags: c++

i was looking in the Stack over flow to best way to return different value types from function in c++
i found few ways which are cool especially this method which is as close as it can be :
[C++ same function parameters with different return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840173/c-same-function-parameters-with-different-return-type)

but there is problem . 
The Value Object can take/cast only strings so if i have something like this :

```
Value RetrieveValue(std::string key)
{
     //get value
      int value = get_value(key, etc);
      return { value };
}
```

im getting :

```
error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'ReturnValue'

no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"
```

my question is can i modify Value object to support also bool and float and int?

```
struct Value
{
    std::string _value;

    template<typename T>
    operator T() const   //implicitly convert into T
    {
       std::stringstream ss(_value);
       T convertedValue;
       if ( ss >> convertedValue ) return convertedValue;
       else throw std::runtime_error("conversion failed");
    }
}
```

also why do the "value" are returned in : `{ value }`
curly brackets??

Comment: The value object given *already* supports the types you've listed with the implicit `operator T()`. The error message you've given suggests that your code is very different from the samples you're showing. It would help if you showed us the code you're *actually* trying to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` has no constructor taking an `int` alone. So you can't direct initialize a `std::string` with one.

You can make it compile with `std::to_string`, however

```
Value RetrieveValue(std::string key)
{
     //get value
      int value = get_value(key, etc);
      return { std::to_string(value) };
}
```

---

To answer your questions in the comments:

1. `{std::to_string(value)}` [aggregate initializes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) a `Value` object, the return value of your function.
2. The implicit conversion to any `T` happens *outside* of your function call. When the compiler need to assign the `Value` you returned to some variable, it looks for a proper conversion. Which the templated conversion operator provides.

---

Per your second comment. If you want to support only fundamental types, you can dispense of the exception in favor of a `static_assert` on [`std::is_fundamental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental):

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const   //implicitly convert into T
{
   static_assert(std::is_fundamental<T>::value, "Support only fundamental types");
   std::stringstream ss(_value);
   T convertedValue;
   ss >> convertedValue
   return convertedValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , can you please explain 2 things i dont understand 
1. why is the return is passed with curly brackets 
2. how does this //implicitly convert into T works 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks allot , say do you know any better way to return different types from  function ?

Comment: @user63898 - There are no absolutes I'm afraid. The best approach depends on what one is trying to accomplish. If say you want to avoid throwing an exception, and support only as fixed set of return types, you can simply overload `operator X` for each type `X` you want to support. And that will produce a compile time error instead of a rune time one. But again, it all depends on your application's needs.

Comment: what do you mean overlod operator X ? i do need fixed types only primitives, also all those stringstream to type conversions worries me

Comment: @user63898 - I that if you need to support say only `int` `char` and `double`, you overload specifically only `operator int`, `operator char` and `operator double`. But you say you want to support only fundamental types? Let me edit a recommendation into my answer.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer , say what about way to avoid the stringstream converts ? any way to do that ?
now i also see i have problem when i need also support std::string which is not fundamental , so for your first answer to overload each type with 
operator X ? what did yo mean by that ?

Comment: @user63898 - Not if your use `std::string`. But the topic of what you shuold use instead is too broad, and comments aren't really for extended discussion. You'd have to examine your code base to figure out an alternative.