# What are ways around not being able to overload a function based on its return type?

Tags: c++, inheritance

http://pastebin.com/afsNHhCu
(I'm only including the code because people always ask for it. This code will not compile right now though)

I wrote up a small crawler game (not really a game yet though), and I'm having an issue with the function that looks up what's on a given square. 
A wrote a function, search_coord, that searches the database to see if an object is on a given square, and returns whatever it finds. It worked fine when I was only dealing with a few simple classes, but I've tried incorporating inheritance since then, and I can't figure out how to make it work now.

Originally, the return type of search_coord was Object& (Object is a base class that most other classes are derived from). I stored all the objects in a database in the form of vector of Objects. 
I needed to create a couple more databases though (for Npcs and graphics), and
I thought that because Object is a base class, search_coord would be capable of returning derived classes as well (apparently the not).

I tried overloading search_coord to deal with different derived types, but the only difference is the return type, and you can't overload based on that. 
Then, I tried using a functor (which is in the code above). This almost works, except that the overloaded (null?) operator isn't capable of taking arguments, which are required for the function to work. The only way around that I could see was to internally incorporate the arguments into the search_coord functor, and change them separately every time I need to call search_coord. That seems like an over complicated idea, so I'm probably going to scratch the functor all together. 
If search_coord was a member of Object, it would be easy. I could just make it virtual, and redefine it in all derived classes (if I understand it's use correctly). The problem is, it has to be (as far as I can tell) a member of database. I tried making it a member of Object, but realized that I wasn't sure what instance of Object to call the function on (given the purpose of the function is to find an instance of Object).

Any help here would be much appreciated!

(I just had an idea while writing this. Could I make the search_coord function virtual static, so that I'm not calling any 1 instance of Object to use it?)

Thank you

Comment: How would the overload be resolved (i.e. how would anyone know which implementation is/should be call/ed)?

Comment: (I'm not advocating making it so complicated, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value)

Comment: @delnanIm not asking for ways to directly overload based on return type, but how to do what I'm trying to do, which would involve overloading based on return type, if that was possible. I just need to know what path to try.

Comment: @user2864740 That's the functor method that I mentioned. It works, but it doesn't allow you to pass anything, so anyime that I used it, I would have to first change some internal values of the functor with a separate function, then use the functor. You're right, it does make it overly complicated.