# Overload Base class virtual function from template Derived class

Tags: c++

I want several datas accessible from a pointer table. Datas can be of any type (eg: int, double, string).
I have created a Base class to use pointers from and I want to derive a template class which will do the typing.

I got the following message and I don't know what is wrong (even if I have a strong feeling that I misunderstand a lot...) :

> error: ‘virtual double Base::get_value()’ cannot be overloaded with ‘virtual int Base::get_value()’

```
class Base
{
    public :        
        virtual int get_value() = 0;
        virtual double get_value() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
    private :
        T m_value;
        
    public :
        Derived(T val):Base(), m_value(val) {}
    
        virtual T get_value() { return m_value; }
};
```

Comment: Do you understand how overloading works? You must have either a different number of arguments, different types of arguments or different sequence of arguments. Your `get_value()` functions fulfill none of these criteria.

Comment: please also fix the other typos. I already added a `;` but there is at least one more (`m_value` vs `value`)

Comment: Isn't it the covariant return type problem ? Inheritance works at runtime, but compilation needs to know the return type.

Comment: The design is wrong. Even if you could have the overloads you want, each derived class would only override a single pure virtual.

Comment: This is the dupe I would close with for your current error (https://stackoverflow.com/a/228923/2602718), but it doesn't really fulfill what your overall issue is (the answer to which will be that you probably need to make base a template class)

Comment: @scohe001 Thank you for the link. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload a function based on the return type alone. Hence this cannot work:

```
class Base
{
    public :        
        virtual int get_value() = 0;
        virtual double get_value() = 0;
};
```

If you call `b->get_value()` there is no way to disambiguate the two.

Next in `Derived` you probably want to override the method from the base, for this use the keyword `override` to make your intent clear and get better compiler errors::

```
virtual T get_value() override { return m_value; }
```

However, due to the issue in `Base` this won't work either. You need to rethink your design. A derived class must implement **all** abstract methods of `Base` to be a non-abstract class. You cannot pick which one to implement.

It looks like you are trying to reimplement something similar to [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Neither of the two is trivial to implement from scratch. If you care about your own implementation then I suggest you to look at how they are implemented. If not, just use them.